# Empty Output file after doing the mapreduce (hadoop)

Tags: java, hadoop

Hi so I got this problem that happened when I tried to use a jar on hadoop. But my Output folder is empty and I got this error message. I was wondering how can I fix this problem ? I saw some post on stack that said that I needed to change a property to this one -> mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent. But I can't find where it's located I tried to see in mapred-site.xml but there is no line similar to this one. Also I am not really sure if this line would fix anything. [image]

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, it is evident that the job failed. The map task has failed (Failedmap tasks=4). Check additional logs to correct the issue with the code.

A folder with the same application ID will be created in the logs/userlogs of your Hadoop installation directory. For example:
HADOOP_INSTALLATION_DIR/logs/userlogs/application_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxx

You can check the syslog and sysout messages.

Comment: There are the error message I saw :
`2021-03-17 21:15:58,139 ERROR [Thread-56] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Could not deallocate container for task attemptId attempt_1616028416776_0003_r_000000_0`

Comment: ```2021-03-17 21:15:59,206 ERROR [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Container complete event for unknown container container_1616028416776_0003_01_000005```

Comment: How do I fix this ?